# How to reverse the effect of the following execution by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove a cookie by using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802354/how-to-remove-a-cookie-by-using-javascript)

```
javascript:void(document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;path=/; domain=.google.com”);
```

How to eliminate the result of the statement above by writing another Javascript statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a cookie, do the same thing but set an expire date in the past:

In this case:

> document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;
>   expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=.google.com”

The key is the addition of **expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;**

Comment: javascript:void(document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/; domain=.google.com”);  does not work.

Comment: Your cookie domain is .google.com, if you're not actually running the code from that domain you will not be able to modify the cookie.