# How to remove a cookie by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How to remove the cookie set by

```
javascript:void(document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;path=/; domain=.google.com”);
```

The following statement doesn't work.

```
javascript:void(document.cookie=”PREF=ID=20b6e4c2f44943bb:U=4bf292d46faad806:TM=1249677602:LM=1257919388:S=odm0Ys-53ZueXfZG;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/; domain=.google.com”);
```

What's wrong with the removal code?

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of adding a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802275/how-to-reverse-the-effect-of-the-following-execution-by-using-javascript/1802283#1802283

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick is right... in particular you need to put any past-value in the `expires` header. (These days you'd use a full-year, though; the two-digit format goes back to the early Netscapes only.)

Also ensure you don't use smart quotes like in your quote above.

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie='PREF=X;path=/;domain=.google.com;expires=Sat, 01-Jan-2000 00:00:00 GMT');
```

Note that the format produced by `Date.toGMTString` is *not* the same as the date format required by the cookie specification, although it does still work in many browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Your cookie domain is **.google.com**, if you're not actually running the code from that domain you will not be able to modify the cookie.

Comment: I run the code from the domain. I typed it in the address bar after I opened Google.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just stick with one question or figure it out for yourself rather than keep posting your problems every few minutes?

e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802210/how-to-recover-google-classic-design-from-its-new-design

[How to reverse the effect of the following execution by using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802275/how-to-reverse-the-effect-of-the-following-execution-by-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT
```

Set time one second after midnight

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, @bobince.  The [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.cookie) says to use [`Date.toUTCString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) for cookie expiration dates.

I am 95% sure that you must set an expiration date when creating the cookie crumb if you want to force its removal later.  A cookie crumb created without an explicit expiration date is a session cookie (crumb) by default, which means that it is not removed until the browser is closed.  I recall trying to expire a session cookie to no avail, in the past.

If you do set an expiration date on the cookie crumb in the first place, remember that you can use a variable for the new expiration date.

```
// assuming a non-session cookie crumb called "someCrumbName" exists:
var now = new Date();
var expirationDate = new Date();
var someValue = "foo";

// set the expiration date to a week ago and delete the cookie
expirationDate.setDate(now.getDate() - 7);
document.cookie = "someCrumbName=" + someValue + ";expires=" + expirationDate.toUTCString();
```